# Horizontal LongListSelector and/or alternatives

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

On one page in my project (Windows Phone 8 C#/XAML App) I have a pivotcontrol containing grid of custom buttons on every page.

Now, since I don't need the headers, it's without them, but I want/need an indicator stating which pivot is selected and/or a way to select pivot without swiping.

That's why I have a created a custom radiobutton-like control by styling a button and adding "Selected" dependency property to it. Now I'd like to make a HORIZONTAL list of those buttons and use them to select pivotitems.

I've been searching for a way to make horizontal longlistselector, but can't find anything useful.

What I'd like to achieve is something like this:

```
--------------------------------
|       USERPANEL - DONE       | //done
|------------------------------|
| ------------    ------------ |
| |          |    |          | |
| | button   |    | button   | |  //buttons and everything else is done
| |          |    |          | |
| ------------    ------------ |
| ------------    ------------ |
| |          |    |          | |
| | button   |    | button   | |
| |          |    |          | |
| ------------    ------------ |
| ------------    ------------ |
| |          |    |          | |
| | button   |    | button   | |
| |          |    |          | |
| ------------    ------------ |
|                              |
|    ===  ---  ---  ---  ---   | //this is the line with horizontal list
|                              | //of buttons 
-------------------------------- // === is selected button, --- is not selected
```

Now, all of the layouts and buttons are there and working, but I'd like to make the longlistselector in the bottom, using my buttons

So my questions are:

**How to make a horizontal longListSelector?**

**Should I use something else instead? Is there an easy alternative?**

**Is it even a good way to use longlistselector like that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a `LongListSelector` is designed for handling large amount of data. I don't think you need it in this case.

A much simpler way would be -

1. Create a `Grid` panel and put it to bottom of your screen and divide its width by the number of controls you want to put in.
2. Create `RadioButtons` and simply style them to `Button`. This way you don't even need to create your custom `Button` control. Also `RadioButton` handles 'de-selecting' automatically, another thing you don't need to do manually.

Answer (score 1):

Well I've used the `WrapPanel` for something similar! You get a Horizontal or Vertical layout...

Take a look at an in depth example here: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-wrappanel-in-depth